# time series - calculating the daily average without 29.02 in python

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

the problem is about the daily average. I have list of rainfall(mm) as below,

```
Y = [ 22,
    29,
    4,
    7,
    10,
    3,
    ...]
```

and X is the time series ,

```
X= [datetime.date(1991, 1, 1),
datetime.date(1991, 1, 2),
datetime.date(1991, 1, 3),
...
datetime.date(2017, 12, 13),
datetime.date(2017, 12, 14),
datetime.date(2017, 12, 15),]
```

the length of X and Y is same. I could used it to plot it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z25xC.png)

I want to calculate the daily average in list but skip the day 29.02 in every 
leap year (so the length of average list is 365),
and also consider incomplete year (for example in this question there are only 11 months and 15 days in 2017), so the new list (assume Z) would looks like this

```
Z = [ 28,
     19,
     ...
     20]

and len(Z) = 365
```

Is anyone have a clever way to solve this question? The ways I tried are always lengthy and stupid. Thank you from the bottom of my heart in advance.

Comment: Share data and your code. Please have a look here: [ask]

Comment: In `Y `you have one item per day sines  01.01.1991?

Comment: @AntonvBR I have corrected it, thanks for your friendly reminder.

Comment: @iliatimofeev yes

Comment: Or your idea is to drop all 29 february from calculations and pretend like is only 28 days in that monthes?

Comment: @iliatimofeev exactly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` TimeSeries has that functionality 
[Series.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html)

**Update 4**
Annual mean by date calculation

**Update 3**

```
#fixed bug in leap dates
```

**Update 2** drop all 29 feb from calculations

**Update 1** with data from question

If you sure that Y has values for all days since 01.01.1991 then

```
Y = [ 22,29,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(Y, 
        index = pd.date_range('01.01.1991',periods = len(Y),freq ='D', name = 'date'),
        columns = ['rainfall'])
df
```

Output:

```
date    rainfall
1991-01-01  22
1991-01-02  29
1991-01-03  4
```

To drop all 02-29 set them `np.NaN` it will exclude them from calculation

```
leap_y = pd.Timestamp('29.02.1992') + pd.to_timedelta(1461*np.arange(7),'D')

df.loc[leap_y,'rainfall']=np.NaN
print(df['2000-02-28':'2000-03-01'])
```

Output:

```
            rainfall
date                
2000-02-28      86.0
2000-02-29       NaN
2000-03-01      83.0
```

Annual mean by day.

```
anual = df.groupby([df.index.month.rename('month'),
                    df.index.day.rename('day')]).mean().dropna()
anual
```

Output:

```
 month  day rainfall
 1  1   49.75
 1  2   53.96296296296296
 #.......................
 12 30  48.666666666666664
 12 31  57.48148148148148
```

Comment: The first half is very helpful, but in the end I would like to calculate the daily average in a year (so average 01.01, average 02.01, average 03.01 ...and so on), so a new list would contain 365 data and each of it is an average value.

Comment: Now I understand your question :)

Comment: You can get correct annual mean for 29 february on leap  years, just skip `df[leap_y]=np.NaN`

Comment: Thanks a lot! How terse and vigorous :D